# Mix core and net462: NU1001 The dependency ClassLib4 could not be resolved?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have configured web `asp.core` project (xproj) to use `.net framework 4.6.2` (in project.json);
Then I have created and referenced some class libraries (classic csproj). Three of them were referenced without problem, but referencing forth lib I got

```
NU1001 The dependency ClassLib4 could not be resolved
```

error under "References" tree.

All class lib projects are build for framework 4.6.2. Web Core project configured as...

```
"frameworks": {
    "net462": {
       "dependencies": {
          "ClassLib1": {"target": "project"},
          "ClassLib2": {"target": "project"},
          "ClassLib3": {"target": "project"},
          "ClassLib4": {"target": "project"}
       }
   }
}
```

I understand that my ClassLib4 have a reference to some NUGET packags that somehow linked to framework "older" then .NET Framework 4.6.2; (I guess one from EF CORE hell).

So first question is **how to find this NUGET package?** "Consolidate referenices" on solution doesn't show anything.

`dotnet restore` and `dotnet restore --no-cache` doesn't help; Even make a situation worse: I got an errors (now about whole 4 libs):

Errors in D:\cot\Vse\AdminkaV1\Web\project.json
    Unable to resolve 'ClassLib1' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.
    Unable to resolve 'ClassLib2' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.
    Unable to resolve 'ClassLib3' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.
    Unable to resolve 'ClassLib4' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.

Important: But ClassLib1, ClassLib2, ClassLib2 depends only on one System lib!

So I have tere also tooling error. Let check version:

PM> dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003131

**Why it is preview ? I have installed only stable versions! Is it a last version? Which nuget package I should update to get latest dotnet command ( tooling?) version?**

I'm using VS 2015 Update 3

Comment: AFAIK, 1.0.0-preview2-003131 is the version of the Visual Studio tooling for .NET Core, not for .NET itself.

Comment: @QuietSeditionist Thank you for showing interest! You are correct, but how I understand this: dotnet ps command - is part of the "tooling". Toolimng could be builded to run on Core, but tooling is just "script to prepare CS compiler/ MSBuild call". So it is possible to have tooling "Core" and compile to .NET Framework 4.6.2.